# Why does MongoDB server: bad auth : Authentication failed occured?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

When I use dotenv in my code then this type of error occurred.I console log process.env and it works fine but when I use this in uri then it occurs bad auth error.What should I do Now?
[this is my cmd snipping shot[][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k8X0i.png)

Comment: Show some code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: plz provide the code used for the connection to a clear understanding